# Can the Gmail UI be embedded into a web application to interact with the web application (bidirectional)?

Tags: gmail-api

Is it possible to embed the whole Gmail UI into a web application and control it out of my web application (e.g. select a message by its sender) as well as the other way around that the web application can register, e.g. by callbacks, the activities going on in the Gmail UI (e.g. get all data from the selected/opened message)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed the options available like maybe you could add an iFrame with the Gmail web interface to accomplish this. However, I found that Gmail, like most of Google's other web services, sets the HTTP header:
`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`

Because of this, it disables the option of using an iFrame to access Gmail.

The only options available will be the Gmail API with [this Google Cloud service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/?csw=1)

Or you can build your setup using the Gmail API, and link it to buttons in your web application that will call the methods to [send email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending), [searching for Messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering), [work with Drafts](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts), etc. You can read more information about the Gmail API [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api).

Lastly, you can submit a missing feature request by following the information in [this Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/support#missing_features), so they can add the feature later on.

Comment: Thanks! Seems it is not possible of using the Gmail UI completely and instead using the Gmail API in conjunction with self-developed widgets, e.g. to list all messages from a Gmail account.

Comment: You are welcome. Hopefully Google can release something in the future that can allow this to happen. If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)